# Moving Local In-house Intranet to an aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

To summarize my current scenario - My company has its own in-house local servers. We are looking to migrate all applications (including web apps) hosted on these servers to the cloud so there is no reliance on in-house servers. We will then retire them if possible.
When users are in the office, they are connected to a LAN system and can access the data, applications, web applications, intranet websites, ect.. on those servers.
When users are out of the office working remotely, they need to vpn into the network and then have the same level of access as if they were on the LAN system.
Our servers are only hosting applications and data pertaining to our own organization.

In particular - we have one server that hosts an asp.net mvc application on IIS that integrates with a SQL Server also installed on the same server. This is an intranet site.

I want to migrate this over to an ec2 instance but had a few questions regarding this:

1. If we didn’t want a user to have to establish a VPN connection, how would we restrict internet traffic to only IP addresses associated with our company? If a new employee joins our company, would we need to manually (or through aws api) add the associated computer to the security group?
2. Since some data being trafficked may be sensitive we would need to use secure HTTP. Right now on our local server hosting the intranet site, we are able to use a self signed SSL Certificate. Would we be able to do something similar on an EC2 instance without buying an approved public SSL certificate? Would we need to purchase a public domain for something like this? I am extremely limited in knowledge when it comes to security certificates.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your ideas about securing the intranet website in the cloud would need some adjustment. You are thinking of "lift and shift" your on-prem environment to the cloud. There are two ways to approach it:

**Keep the application as - is and replicate the on-prem-like security model:**

So all the security is based on securing the "physical perimeter" of your network. Here your intranet web server would reside in a private subnet and will be accessible to the users only via VPN or Direct Connect.

While you can configure the security group to allow inbound traffic for selected IP addresses only, it would not solve the problem for travelling employees and dynamically allocated IP addresses. It is also prone to other types of attacks such as IP spoofing. Inbound IP filtering can make an already secure system more secure, but it would not turn the insecure system into a secure one.

**Harden the application so it can be securely accessible over the public internet:**

Here you are on the right track with the SSL/TLS certificate. But again, it's just part of the solution. Besides securing the traffic you need to make sure there is a solid Authentication/Authorization framework to make sure only authorized users can access it. And that might require considerable development effort.

BTW - SSL/TLS Certificates are now free of charge with the tools like LetsEncrypt ow AWS Certificate Manager (you'll need to use Load Balancer or CloudFront with ACM though).

By the sound of it - option #1 is easier to start with. But here using VPN is inevitable. You can use [AWS site-to-site VPN for the office and AWS Client VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/) for travelling/work from home employees.